# Lipschitz condition for smooth concave functions

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Given a $C^2$ L-smooth function the Lipschitz condition is:

$$||\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y)||\leq L ||x-y||$$  which give us $$\nabla^2f(x)  \preceq L I.$$ Then, based on the Tayloe expansion $$f(y)=f(x)+\nabla f(x)^T(x-y) + \frac{1}{2}(x-y)^T\nabla^2 f(z)(x-y)$$ with $z$ a convex combination of $x$ and $y$ we may take $$f(y) \leq f(x) + (y-x)^T\nabla f(x) + \frac{L}{2}||y-x||^2.$$

Are these conditions only true for convex $C^2$ function? What will change If $f$ is $C^2$ and concave?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This condition is completely independent of convexity. As long as you can connect any two points in your domain to be able to use the argument, the two conditions are equivalent for $C^2$ functions. This is true for convex domains. No assumption on $f$ is needed, apart from regularity.

Comment: Thanks for answering, sorry I made an edit. The last equation is called descent lemma. Does the inequality stay the same?

Comment: The answer is yes, as long as you can apply the expansion, and for that the convexity of the domain is enough (to be able to connect any two points within it). You do not need the function to be convex. I will make it explicit in my answer,

Comment: BTW you have a typo in your Taylor expansion with remainder. The term with the gradient should be linear and the term with the Hessian should be quadratic.